# Twitter Lists Widget Limits

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

Is there a way to increase the number of displayed tweets in the Twitter List Widget? The javascript code lets you set a max of 100 tweets but twitters api apparently limits it to 20 tweets.  Is there a work-around or another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the widget is passing `rpp` (results per page) while the [list method](https://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/lists/statuses) uses `count`. Try changing the widget code to use `count`. Otherwise you can try filing a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/list).